# JavaScript Function Parameter - Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is working fine. But, I just want to remove variable `url` in third line and write direct `www.google.com`. Need corrected syntax of below code please. Quotes are so messy! I know there is just a little mistake. But didn't figure out.

```
website: function() {
var url = 'www.google.com';             
this.echo('<a onclick="openHTTP(\''+url+'\')"  href=""> My Website </a>', {raw:true});
```

Comment: `this.echo`? i am confused. Please paste full code along with expected outcome

Comment: Mistakenly added @JonathanLonowski

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to only replace the delimiting quotations (those ending and starting string literals) as well as `+url+`.

```
this.echo('<a onclick="openHTTP(\'www.google.com\')"  href=""> My Website </a>', {raw:true});
```

Noting that your current snippet concatenates 2 literals with the variable:

- `'<a onclick="openHTTP(\''`
- `'\')"  href=""> My Website </a>'`

The escaped quotations should be kept for the client-side code. They'll allow the browser to understand `www.google.com` as a string literal. The `\` will be removed by the parser, so the output includes:

```
<a onclick="openHTTP('www.google.com')"  href="">
```

Comment: @JonathanLonowski solved it correctly.
Marked as correct answer.

Comment: I am waiting for OP's response. removed my  -ve mark

Answer (score 4):

```
website: function() {
        this.echo('<a onclick="openHTTP(\'http://www.google.com\')"  href=""> My Website </a>', {raw:true})
    }
```

please try this one

Answer (score 4):

just replace `"url"` variable with `"www.google.com"`

```
this.echo('<a onclick="openHTTP('www.google.com')"  href=""> My Website </a>', {raw:true});
```

Comment: just replace "url" variable with "www.google.com".
This will Work fine.